# near "/" syntax error in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

The below code in my project calls a function in my database class to insert two values into my sqlite database

```
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addCig = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cigName );
            myDbHelper1.insertNewCig(addCig.toString(), fileName );     
        }
    });
```

Here is the insert into function.  I am getting an error that reads (near "/": syntax error). Can anybody help me look into it and see what is wrong with my code.

```
public void insertNewCig(String name, String file)
{
    //DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.newdb/databases/"
    //DB_NAME = "cigarettes"
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    String row1 = "INSERT INTO " + myPath + " (" + KEY_FIRST + ", " +  KEY_LAST + ") VALUES(" + name + ", " + file + ")";
    myDataBase.execSQL(row1);

}
```

Comment: what do you think that is supposed to do, and why do you think you should give the path to the database at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myPath` should be the name of a table in your database, not the name and path of the database file. You also need to add single quotes around the values you are inserting, otherwise SQLite won't recognize that they are literal string values and not something else (e.g. column names). This is one of many reasons not to try to build raw SQL statements by hand in code.

Since you have a `SQLiteDatabase`, you may as well use its [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) methods instead of `execSQL()`. In that case you would give it a `ContentValues` instead of constructing a raw statement, which obviates the need to wrap the string values with single quotes.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_FIRST, name);
values.put(KEY_LAST, file);
myDataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Comment: @Branco30 excellent, glad it worked for you. When you get a chance, please mark this answer with the checkmark so others know it was the solution.